# How can I notify a consumer of a service state has changed

Tags: swift, state

I have a service, somewhat like the below. When I request a user profile, I store it in a collection as a local cache within the service. I then check if it exists on subsequent requests and return it if it does.

I have another method on the service that updates a user profile. The response for this change gets a new, updated copy of `user`. However this service is injected into 2 different view models, it is the same instance as it is created higher in the chain. It is not a singleton instance.

If controller A renders the results of `fetchUserProfile` and controller B renders the results of `updateText`, how can I update controller A when `users: [String: User]` is changed?

I need a way to notify that something changed in the service.

I did consider something simple like a closure and calling it on `didSet` but not sure if this is the right way or can be handled better?

something like -

```swift
          private var users: [String: User] = [:] {
                 didSet { 
                   usersChange?(users)
                 } 
            }
```

But then I want to introduce some sort of time based eviction on this collection later down the line and call `didSet` would not make much sense, I also feel like at this point every output from the service would be spread across the method and this closure / binding

```
    final class ProfileService: ProfileServiceType {

        private let client: Client<InternalEndpoints>
        private var users: [String: User] = [:] 

        enum ProfileServiceError: Error {
            case invalidMediaPayload
        }

        init(client: Client<InternalEndpoints>) {
            self.client = client
        }

        func fetchUserProfile(byId userId: String) -> Promise<User> {

            if let cached = users[userId] {
                return .value(cached)
            }

            return client
                .request(.getUserProfile(userId: userId))
                .get { [weak self] in self?.users[userId] = $0 }
        }

        func updateText(forUser userId: String, with text: String) -> Promise<User> {

            return client
                .request(.updateProfileText(userId: userId, text: text))
        }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you want, but probably KVO or delegation could help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: If I were you I'd be using core data or realm. Then you can just observe changes in the persistence layer. Is there a reason why you are sharing an instance of the `ProfileService`? Doesn't seem like a good idea. Anyways, sure, you can use a closure like you did above or you can use a delegate. Another option is to use `NotificationCenter.post` and `NotificationCenter.addObserver`.